# div nested in code

Tags: html

I'm using a series of `div` and `span` tags as hooks for CSS styles for purposes of highlighting syntax of lines of code that I wanted to post on a web blog.  Each line is put on it's own list element in an ordered list.

So it may look something like this, for example:

```
<div class="json">
    <ol>
    <li class="li1"><div class="de1"><span class="br0">&#123;</span></div></li>
    <li class="li2"><div class="de2"> <span class="st0">&quot;files&quot;</span><span class="sy0">:</span><span class="br0">&#91;</span></div></li>
    <li class="li1"><div class="de1">  <span class="br0">&#123;</span></div></li>
    <li class="li2"><div class="de2">  <span class="st0">&quot;url&quot;</span><span class="sy0">:</span><span class="st0">&quot;http://www.blah.com&quot;</span><span class="sy0">,</span></div></li>
    <li class="li1"><div class="de1">  <span class="st0">&quot;lastModified&quot;</span><span class="sy0">:</span><span class="nu0">1348750586000</span></div></li>
    <li class="li2"><div class="de2">  <span class="br0">&#125;</span></div></li>
    <li class="li1"><div class="de1"> <span class="br0">&#93;</span></div></li>
    <li class="li2"><div class="de2"><span class="br0">&#125;</span></div></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I wanted to give the markup extra semantic meaning by placing it between `code` tags, because it is actually lines of code (although with extra markup), e.g.

```
<code>
    <div class="json">
        <ol>
        <li class="li1"><div class="de1"><span class="br0">&#123;</span></div></li>
        <li class="li2"><div class="de2"> <span class="st0">&quot;files&quot;</span><span class="sy0">:</span><span class="br0">&#91;</span></div></li>
        <li class="li1"><div class="de1">  <span class="br0">&#123;</span></div></li>
        <li class="li2"><div class="de2">  <span class="st0">&quot;url&quot;</span><span class="sy0">:</span><span class="st0">&quot;http://www.blah.com&quot;</span><span class="sy0">,</span></div></li>
        <li class="li1"><div class="de1">  <span class="st0">&quot;lastModified&quot;</span><span class="sy0">:</span><span class="nu0">1348750586000</span></div></li>
        <li class="li2"><div class="de2">  <span class="br0">&#125;</span></div></li>
        <li class="li1"><div class="de1"> <span class="br0">&#93;</span></div></li>
        <li class="li2"><div class="de2"><span class="br0">&#125;</span></div></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</code>
```

Yet, `code` cannot contain `div` elements per the html5 w3c validation service.  So do I forgo the use of the `code` tag altogether?  Or do I try to rewrite everything without `div`'s at all?  I'm not sure because in my particular use of `code` I'm adding extra markup for CSS syntax highlighting purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the `code` tag instead of a `span` tag? They're both inline elements I think so it should be fine.

Comment: This seems like the best (and quickest for me!) approach to have the best of both worlds.  Thanks for the idea!